# Obtain probabilities from logits - logits and labels not the same size

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use Tensorflow to classify some object representations. I used the same architecture as in the Tensorflow Cifar-10 example, with the last layer defined as:

```
    with tf.variable_scope('sigmoid_linear') as scope:
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', [192, num_classes],
                                               stddev=1 / 192.0, wd=0.0)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [num_classes],
                                   initializer)
    sigmoid_linear = tf.add(tf.matmul(local4, weights), biases, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(sigmoid_linear)

return sigmoid_linear
```

In my case, `num_classes` is `2`, and the amount of channels in the representation fed to the neural network is 8. Furthermore, I'm currently debugging with only 5 examples. The output of the last layer has a shape of`[40,2]`. I expect the first dimension is due to `5 examples * 8 channels` and the second due to the number of classes.

In order to use compare the logits and the labels using e.g. `tensorflow.nn.SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits` I need them to have a common shape. How can I interpret the current content of the logits in the current shape, and how can I reduce the first dimension of the logits to be the same as `num_classes`?

Edit: the shape of the input to the inference function has a shape of `[5,101,1008,8]`. The inference function is defined as:

```
    def inference(representations):
    """Build the model.
  Args:
    STFT spectra: spectra returned from distorted_inputs() or inputs().
  Returns:
    Logits.
  """    
    # conv1
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
        kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights',
                                                  shape=[5, 5, nChannels, 64],
                                                  stddev=5e-2,
                                                  wd=0.0)
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(representations, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], initializer,
                                  )
        pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
        conv1 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
        _activation_summary(conv1)

    # pool1
    pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                           padding='SAME', name='pool1')
    # norm1
    norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(pool1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                      name='norm1')

    # conv2
    with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:
        kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights',
                                                  shape=[5, 5, 64, 64],
                                                  stddev=5e-2,
                                                  wd=0.0)
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(norm1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], initializer)
        pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
        conv2 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
        _activation_summary(conv2)

    # norm2
    norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(conv2, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                      name='norm2')
    # pool2
    pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(norm2, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                           strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool2')

    # local3
    with tf.variable_scope('local3') as scope:
        # Move everything into depth so we can perform a single matrix multiply.
        reshape = tf.reshape(pool2, [batch_size, -1])
        dim = reshape.get_shape()[1].value
        weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[dim, 384],
                                                   stddev=0.04, wd=0.004)
        biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [384], initializer)
        local3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
        _activation_summary(local3)

    # local4
    with tf.variable_scope('local4') as scope:
        weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[384, 192],
                                                   stddev=0.04, wd=0.004)
        biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [192], initializer)
        local4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(local3, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
        _activation_summary(local4)


    with tf.variable_scope('sigmoid_linear') as scope:
        weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', [192, num_classes],
                                                   stddev=1 / 192.0, wd=0.0)
        biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [num_classes],
                                       initializer)
        sigmoid_linear = tf.add(tf.matmul(local4, weights), biases, name=scope.name)
        _activation_summary(sigmoid_linear)

    return sigmoid_linear
```

Answer (score 0):

After more debugging I could find the problem. The posted code with the layers, originally from the Tensorflow tutorial, works well (of course it does). I printed all shapes, after each layer, and found out that the number `40` was not due to `5 examples * 8 channels`, but that I had previously set `batch_size = 40`, and thus also higher than the amount of training examples. The mismatch began after the reshaping in the `local layer 3`. The question can now be closed.